# Subquery for same column but separate values?

Tags: sql, ms-access, subquery

All right, I don't know how to ask this, so I'll just post the query and see if someone can help make it work.
I'm using Access, if that helps. I would post the tables but I don't know how, so if someone can explain how to do that I'll post those too.

```
SELECT Pokemon.SpeciesID, Pokemon.FormID, SpeciesName, 
Type.TypeName AS Type1 WHERE Type.TypeID = SpeciesType.TypeID AND SpeciesType.IsPrimaryType IS true, 
Type.TypeName AS Type2 WHERE Type.TypeID = SpeciesType.TypeID AND SpeciesType.IsPrimaryType IS false,
FROM Pokemon, Type, SpeciesType;
```

I know this is wrong, I need the WHERE parts after the FROM, but I can't figure out how to make that work.

Yes, I have to select type twice, there is very literally *no way whatsoever* for me to not have to do that. There's a many-to-many join table (dunno what to call this) that has the TypeID, SpeciesID, and an indicator of whether that row is the species's primary type or not. I need to select those with that as true AND those with that as false within one query.

(This is related to a school project.)

EDIT: Since nobody's explaining how to post a table, here's a screenshot of the relationships, doctored to highlight what's relevant.
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/28505565/bluh/school/relationships.png
IsPrimaryType is a yes/no column. I need to select the Yes as Type1 and No as Type2.

Comment: Please put the table and explain what you need to get from it. thanks

Comment: Um... okay, how do I format it to put here? This is done in Access, not MySQL, so the tables don't have an SQL equivalent offhand.

Comment: Connecting tables in the FORM statement using `Table1, Table2, ...` isn't a good idea. Use JOIN's instead

Comment: Okay, so I'm just dumb and don't know what I'm doing, apparently. How would you use a join on all those at once without ending up with a tangled mess of a statement?

Comment: if your using access and unsure of sql , might it be easier to use the wizard?

Comment: Your current query joins every single row of each of those tables. Hence if there were 100 rows on each table you would land up with 100 x 100 x 100 = 1,000,000 rows to process. You can put the join clauses in the WHERE but better to use Pokemon INNER JOIN Type ON Pokemon.SomeField = Type.SomeOtherField INNER JOIN SpeciesType ON Pokemon.Some3rdField = SpeciesType.Some4thField . To get the values you can use an IIF (immediate if) statement in the SELECT

Comment: First questions you have to answer: which columns in the tables have the same values. Those are used for the JOINS. Example `... FROM (Type INNER JOIN SpeciesType ON Type.TypeID = SpeciedType.TypeID) JOIN Pokemon ON Pokemon.?1 = ?2.?3` where you should replace ?1 with a column in Pokemon, ?2 is either the table Types or SpeciesType and ?3 is a column in it.

Comment: Nobody's explaining how to post a table so here's a snapshot of the relationships, doctored a bit to highlight the relevant tables. The underlined tables are the ones needed here. https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/28505565/bluh/school/relationships.png
IsPrimaryType is a true/false. I need to select rows from that table that have that as true (Type1) and _in the same table and a different column_ select rows with that as false (Type2). Does that help?

Comment: Steven Smith: The teacher specified not to, but I was desperate enough anyhow; it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use the Switch function in your SELECT statement?

```
SELECT Pokemon.SpeciesID, Pokemon.FormID, SpeciesName,
switch(
SpeciesType.IsPrimaryType IS true, Type.TypeName,
true, ''
) AS Type1,
switch(
SpeciesType.IsPrimaryType IS false, Type.TypeName,
true, ''
) AS Type2
```

Read more about the Switch function here: http://office.microsoft.com/en-sg/access-help/switch-function-HA001228918.aspx

Comment: This is very close. My only problem is that it shows each of the two in separate rows. https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/28505565/bluh/school/separate-rows.png Is there a way to circumvent this or am I just out of luck?

Comment: You can do a FULL JOIN of two tables where one table consits of records where IsPrimaryType is true and another table with records where IsPrimaryType is false.

Alternatively, you can try ConcatRelated (http://allenbrowne.com/func-concat.html).

Answer (score 0):

ok so here goes....please note as i Dont know what you table or fields are this is a very VERY rough guide

```
SELECT 
    Pokemon.SpeciesID, Pokemon.FormID, SpeciesName, Type1, Type2
FROM 
Pokemon
INNER JOIN 
pokemon.ID = speciestype.id
INNER JOIN
    typetable.id = pokemon.id
```

as you can note select all the fields from all the tables that you need.

next join you 1st table to you second, they need a relationship, in this case we will simply say i want only the records that match, on this tables id and the others ID (IF THAT IS THE CASE, thats for you to work out which fields are linked)!
do that same again and bingo

next you may need to filter, so add the WHERE clause and filter, i want only where type = true.

So you would say,

```
WHERE yourtable.type = 'true'
```

notice its in string format as i don't know what your field type is.

UPDATE: also the extra info given you should be able to deduce whats needed, we could do this for you looking at all the information. BUT as this is an assignment I would take the guidance from here, and google and figure the rest out, best way to learn is to do!

Good luck !